# Springboot - MongoDB - ValueObject unavailable in mapreduce package

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mapreduce, spring-data-mongodb

Im doing the mapReduce example provided in spring mongodb [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mapreduce), however, the class ValueObject is not available in spring mongodb package:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapreduce
```

Eventhough, it is available in the spring [github repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapreduce/ValueObject.java)

I am using spring boot version 1.5.9.RELEASE

EDIT: One can easily implement it and use it. I am just wondering, did they remove it because it is easy to implement?

Comment: No, it was never available in src package. ValueObject is a test class use by spring team to unit test map reduce.

Comment: Thank you! that confused me for a second. Now it makes sense